# Реально ли оптимизировать функции TRIM и COPY?

Tags: delphi

Реально ли оптимизировать функции **TRIM** и **COPY** на более скоростную работу?

Comment: вы уверены, что bottleneck именно в них?

Comment: мы уверены :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как правило, такие распространенные функции уже оптимизированы достаточно, нет смысла переписывать их по своему. Если их быстродействие критично для программы, можно подумать в сторону предварительной подготовки данных и кеширования результатов.

Comment: Ясно. Будем думать! :)